# Deleting / changing searched text in Vim

Tags: search, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, replace

When I do an interactive search for some pattern, each time I hit `n`, I get the next result. How do I delete / change each result that I come to?

**Ideally, what I'm looking for would work like this: I hit `n` to get the search result, and then `magic command` to highlight that result in visual mode, and then I can do `d` or `c` to delete or change the highlighted text.**

**Example**:

I enter the command

```
/hello .
```

and it matches `hello`, a space, and any character after it.

So say the first match it reaches is "hello w".

Now, I want to delete all of `hello w`, search for the next match (say it is `hello a`), change the next match to `hello there`, and keep doing different things to each match.

I'm not looking for just search-and-replace, because I want to be able to perform *any* action on each result interactively, such as delete the first result, replace the second result with `bye`, and replace the third result with `later`.

Comment: @shoebox639: That would replace all `hello`'s with `hello w`, which isn't what I was looking for :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To select the entire match of the current match (if you are at the start of the match) you can type

```
v//e
```

To delete to the end of the match

```
d//e
```

To change the match

```
c//e
```

Only negative is that you cant use `n` (as that will redo `//e` ) and instead have to use `//`

So typical workflow would look like this

```
/hello ./    : Jump to the start of the next "hello ."
d//e         : Delete the item
//           : repeat the search to get to the begining of the next "hello ."
c//e         : change it
//           : next one.
etc.
```

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for! Awesome! Just to clarify, what exactly does `//e` search for? The end of the match? How does it work?

Comment: A more general question, actually, is, what does `//` search for?

Comment: Actually, I've asked the question separately, please answer it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984622/how-does-the-command-work-in-vim

Answer (score 21):

I think you want `gn`: (Go to the next match and) select it in visual mode. You can prefix this with a command, e.g. `cgn` changes the match, `dgn` deletes etc. I found that if already on a match, this match is used, so that this should do it.

Comment: This should be the answer, it is much more practical!

Comment: This looks awesome. What version of vim supports this? I can't find it in the help of my version, and the command doesn't work for me (I'm on 7.2).

Comment: On another machine I've verified it works on vim 8.0 - so newer vims seem to be OK.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson `gn` was introduced in 7.4.110. (I know I'm 5 years too late, but I just stumbled on this answer and found the relevant information that could be useful for someone else)

Answer (score 2):

I would do what one previous poster suggested:  Construct a single delete command with d *target* and hit . after using n to find each occurrence.  In this case `7x` would delete anything matching `hello .`  That's a shortcut form of `d7l` or `d7[space]` since d takes any movement command.

However, if you want a truly general solution to searching and deleting a regexp, you can execute a single substitution command (even if it fails) and then execute your search and use & to re-apply the last substitution to the current line:

```
:s/hello .//
/hello .
&
n
&
```

The first line (the substitution) can fail.  You can still apply it again with & later.  I'm kind of surprised that the first substitution command doesn't set the default pattern, but maybe it does in vi other than vim.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there some way I can have Vim highlight each match when I come to it in visual mode, so that I can operate on the visually selected text? That would be the optimal solution.

Comment: You can hilite the current search pattern any time by turning on hlsearch (`:set hlsearch`)

Comment: I meant highlight it in visual mode, so I can perform an action on it.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for "confirm"

```
:%s/hello .//gc
```

: to go into ex mode, % to apply to the whole buffer, s to substitute, /hello ./ to search for that regex, // to replace it with nothing, g to look for all matches on a line, and c to confirm whether or not to delete before each match.

That is assuming you are looking for confirm. If you want to just do it all at once, it has been mentioned already a bunch of times

```
:%s/hello .//g
```

: to go into ex mode, % to apply to the whole buffer, s to substitute, /hello ./ to search for that regex, // to replace it with nothing, and g to look for all matches on a line

Comment: I know about confirm, but I was looking for something a little different. Please check out the new bolded text in the question for clarification.

Comment: what you are describing is confirm. You type in the top command, it brings you to the first result and asks if you want to replace. you say "y" or "n", which either does it or doesn't, and moves to the next instance, asking the same question

Answer (score 1):

Change the first one, using `cwfoo`<kbd>esc</kbd> or whatever, then use the `.` command to repeat that edit for each further occurrence that you want to change.

Comment: That changes the *word*, OP wants to delete/replace *text*.

Comment: Okay, so use whatever *text* editing command you need to change what you need to change. It's impossible to recommend something specific without a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this with recordings.

<kbd>qa/</kbd>`textsearch` <kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>v9lvq</kbd>

9 is the (length of `textsearch` - 1) i.e. 10 - 1 = 9

Now once you have prepared the recording in register `a`, do <kbd>@agv</kbd>
( <kbd>@a</kbd>: executes recording named `a` and <kbd>gv</kbd> selects your search text.)

Now you can do whatever with your selected text, once you are done you can go to the next
one with <kbd>@@</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Also for removing all lines containing a string, you can use:

```
:g@search_query@d
```

`g` command to globally search

`@` Separator

`d` command to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Press the x key.

or user search and replace: `[esc] :%s/[search-regex]/[replace-regex]/g`

If `replace-regex` is blank you'll delete whatever you just searched.

Comment: And if you want to replace text, just do [r] and type, then [esc][n][r] then type some more. But a search and replace is probably best for you.

Comment: Doesn't `x` delete just one character? And `r` replace just one character? I'm looking to delete or replace the entire matched text.