# How does the search command `//` work in Vim?

Tags: search, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

After searching for something, if you hit `//`, you seem to get the next result. How is this different from `n`? How should you use it? What does `//e` match, and what other options are there for `//`?

Comment: The FAQ states quite clearly: "software tools commonly used by programmers", so I don't think this should be closed. I don't see many accountants or clerical staff using Vim :-)

Comment: Haha, and there's an entire tag devoted to Vim, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The search command is of the following format:

```
/pattern/offset<cr>
```

If the `pattern` part is left out, the search looks for the last pattern that was searched for. If the offset is left out, no offset is applied. The offset is basically what to do to the cursor once you've found your `pattern` item.

Most `vi` users are familiar with the variation without an offset, `/pax<cr>` and the repeat last search, `/<cr>`, which is equivalent to `n`.

In your specific examples, `//<cr>` is the same as `/<cr>` and it means repeat the last search and apply no offset.

On the other hand, `//e<cr>` means to repeat the last search and move the cursor to the end of the found item. The offsets are:

```
[num]         [num] lines downwards, in column 1
+[num]        [num] lines downwards, in column 1
-[num]        [num] lines upwards, in column 1
e[+num]       [num] characters to the right of the end of the match
e[-num]       [num] characters to the left of the end of the match
s[+num]       [num] characters to the right of the start of the match
s[-num]       [num] characters to the left of the start of the match
b[+num]       [num] identical to s[+num] above (mnemonic: begin)
b[-num]       [num] identical to s[-num] above (mnemonic: begin)
;{pattern}    perform another search, see |//;|
```

A plus or minus without a `num` uses `1`.

Comment: Perfect, solid answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

One of the nice features of `//` is that you can use it with the `s` command. So if you initially search for `/Foo` and then decides to replace that with `Bar`, you can do this without repeating the pattern. Just do `:%s//Bar/g`

Obviously this is a lot more useful if the pattern is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 6):

`//<CR>` means repeat the search for the last pattern with no offset.

`//e<CR>` means repeat the search for the last pattern, but land on the end of the match.

`n` is the same as `/<CR>` in that it uses the last pattern *and* the last offset, however `n` keeps the last direction while `/` always finds the *next* match.

See `:h last-pattern` and `:h search-offset` for a thorough explanation of these commands and their options.

Comment: So does `//` start searching from the top of the file then?

Comment: No, it searches forward from where you are.

Comment: Offset is (generally) where you are in the file, starting from the top. `//` will repeat the search from where you are, whereas `n` will repeat the search from where the last match was.

By the way, you can use `//` in substitute and global commands too. Useful if you've got a particularly tricky bit of matching to do and you want to test it out with a regular search beforehand.